# Caffe - inconsistency in the activation feature values - GPU mode

Tags: python, gpu, caffe

Hi I am using **caffe** on **Ubuntu 14.04**, 
**CUDA version 7.0**  (latest)
**cudnn version 2** (latest)
**GPU : NVIDIA GT 730**

In caffe first I get the initialization done and then I load the imagenet model (Alexnet). I also initialize the gpu using `set_mode_gpu()`
After that I take an image. I copy this image onto the caffe source blob. Then I perform a forward pass for this image by using : `net.forward(end='fc7')`
Then I extract the 4096 dimensional fc7 output.(the activation features of the fc7 layer)

The problem I am facing is that when I run the same code multiple times, everytime I obtain a different result. That is, in GPU mode, everytime the activation features are different for the same image. When I am using forward pass, the function of the network is supposed to be deterministic right ? So I should get the same output everytime for the same image.

On the other hand, when I run caffe on cpu by using `set_mode_cpu()` everything works perfectly, i.e, I get the same output each time
The code used and the outputs obtained are shown below. I am not able to understand what the problem is. Is it that the problem is caused due to GPU rounding off ? But the errors are very large. Or is it due to some issues with the latest CUDNN version ? Or is it something else altogether ?

**Following is the CODE**

## 1) IMPORT libraries

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as nd
import PIL.Image
from IPython.display import clear_output, Image, display
from google.protobuf import text_format
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import caffe
```

## 2) IMPORT Caffe Models and define utility functions

```
model_path = '../../../caffe/models/bvlc_alexnet/' 
net_fn   = model_path + 'deploy.prototxt'
param_fn = model_path + 'bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel'

model = caffe.io.caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
text_format.Merge(open(net_fn).read(), model)
model.force_backward = True
open('tmp.prototxt', 'w').write(str(model))

net = caffe.Classifier('tmp.prototxt', param_fn,
                       mean = np.float32([104.0, 116.0, 122.0]), # ImageNet mean, training set dependent
                       channel_swap = (2,1,0),# the reference model has channels in BGR order instead of RGB
                      image_dims=(227, 227)) 

caffe.set_mode_gpu()
# caffe.set_mode_cpu()

# a couple of utility functions for converting to and from Caffe's input image layout
def preprocess(net, img):
    return np.float32(np.rollaxis(img, 2)[::-1]) - net.transformer.mean['data']
def deprocess(net, img):
    return np.dstack((img + net.transformer.mean['data'])[::-1])
```

## 3) LOADING Image and setting constants

```
target_img = PIL.Image.open('alpha.jpg')
target_img = target_img.resize((227,227), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
target_img=np.float32(target_img)
target_img=preprocess(net, target_img)

end='fc7'
```

## 4) Setting the source image and making the forward pass to obtain fc7 activation features

```
src = net.blobs['data']
src.reshape(1,3,227,227) # resize the network's input image size
src.data[0] = target_img
dst = net.blobs[end]
net.forward(end=end)
target_data = dst.data[0]
print dst.data
```

**FOLLOWING is the output that I obtained for 'print dst.data' when I ran the above code multiple times**

## output on 1st execution of code

```
[[-2.22313166 -1.66219997 -1.67641115 ..., -3.62765646 -2.78621101
  -5.06158161]]
```

## output on 2nd execution of code

```
[[ -82.72431946 -372.29296875 -160.5559845  ..., -367.49728394 -138.7151947
  -343.32080078]]
```

## output on 3rd execution of code

```
[[-10986.42578125 -10910.08105469 -10492.50390625 ...,  -8597.87011719
   -5846.95898438  -7881.21923828]]
```

## output on 4th execution of code

```
[[-137360.3125     -130303.53125    -102538.78125    ...,  -40479.59765625
    -5832.90869141   -1391.91259766]]
```

The output values keep becoming larger and larger and then again become smaller after some time. I am not able to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your network to Test mode to prevent the effect of dropout which is non-deterministic and needed for training mode.

Add the following line right after initializing your network:

net.set_phase_test()

So that you'll always have the same results.

Soner